# Trying to install Spring Tools App 4.7.0 on macOS Catalina

Tags: java, spring, spring-tools-4

Trying to install Sprint Tools 4 on my mac.
Install goes ok, but when I try to open the app I get error messages:

```
"openjdk-11.0.2.jdk" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

Homebrew Cask downloaded this file on 6 February 2019 from jdk.java.net.
```

and then

```
macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

Homebrew Cask downloaded this file on 6 February 2019 from jdk.java.net.
```

Not sure what to do now? Update? Replace with something different?
Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to System Preferences, and open Security & Privacy.
2. In the General Tab, under Allow apps downloaded from, you should see
   the app you’ve been trying to open – click on the Open Anyway button
   to its right.
3. You will once again see a warning message that tells you the app
   cannot be verified as safe, but this time you will have the option
   to open it anyway. If you are certain you want to execute the app, click on
   Open.

Once you do that, you will no longer get the “MacOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware” warning whenever you try to open this particular program, as it will now be added to the exceptions list.

Comment: This is doable. However be careful from bad sites. Use usually official site : https://spring.io/tools

Comment: As an additional comment, the official distribution of Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse for macOS that you download from https://spring.io/tools is signed and notarized and will not cause the above mentioned message to appear.

Comment: Ehh.. no offence now.. but I did download it from spring.io/tools and it did cause the messages I showed above.
The messages were removed by following the steps in M.Mas's answer.

Comment: Perhaps it needs re-signing/notarizing for Catalina 10.15.5 ??